# MySQL bind-address for port 33060 (X-Protocol)

Tags: mysql

in my.cnf I have the following settings

```
port=3306
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Using netstat this shows the following

```
tcp    127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      32673/mysqld
tcp6   :::33060           :::*        LISTEN      32673/mysqld
```

What is the bind-address command for this new [X-Protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/x-protocol.html)

Answer (score 10):

Prefix the same commands with `mysqlx`

```
mysqlx-port=33060
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Also as X-Protocol is now default ON in newer installations, this may be useful

```
mysqlx=OFF
```